# What would be the maximum length of Youtube Channel ID?

Tags: url, youtube

Channel ID is the ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the channel.
What is the max length of it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The max length of youtube channel is 24.
I found out the maximum length from about 20k youtube channel IDs.

Comment: I think the length for youtube channelId is same 24.

Answer (score 1):

All the requests I've made to the API at `https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1` have returned exactly 24 characters for a `channelId`. But this experimentation probably isn't the credible source you wanted.